# Populate a Navigation Controller on First Launch

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

When my app is first launched I want to create some sample data that new users will see. I'd like them to start a level (maybe more) into the navigation controller, like so:

tableViewController0 -> tvc1 (user starts here)

Picture a notes app that has folders as its top level of navigation. You might want to show the user a few sample notes in a sample folder first, then let him/her go back later and create new folders.

My thought was that I'd run a method in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` that would check for first launch (checking/setting a `Bool` in `NSUserDefaults`) and then, if we are in the first launch, create some sample data. Then I thought I could just create each view controller and set my `UINavigationController`'s `viewControllers` property, but I get this error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

(The cell definitely does have an identifier `Cell` in the storyboard and works if I don't create the data and view controllers beforehand.)

Some sample code from my AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // From Xcode's stock AppDelegate
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self

    let masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController

    // Check for first launch, get back a sample object.
    if isFirstLaunch == true {
        let newObject = prepareFirstLaunch()

        let tvc0 = TableViewController0()
        tvc0.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext

        let tvc1 = TableViewController1()
        tvc1.someObject = newObject

        masterNavigationController.viewControllers = [tvc1, tvc0]
    } else {
        // this is moved from the stock AppDelegate down into this else statement.
        let controller = masterNavigationController.topViewController as! TableViewController0
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    }

    return true
}

private func isFirstLaunch() -> Bool {
    // return whether we're launching for the first time
}

private func prepareSampleObject() -> SomeObject {
    /*
    If we're launching for the first time
    create someObject, create some other objects that are owned
    by this object in CoreData, set up their relationships, etc.
    */

    return someObject
}
```

Is there another way I can set this up so the user can jump right into a populated navigation stack rather than having to start at the top level?

Answer (score 0):

You're using storyboards, which means you have an initial view controller.

Make this initial view controller a `UINavigationController` whose `rootViewController` is some `SetupViewController` where all of your checking logic occurs. Show a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in it, or whatever loading animation. Then, depending on what you've found, push either the dummy notes screen or the top-level folder screen.

In the storyboard, you will create two segues from the `SetupViewController`--one to the notes, one to the folder. Give each segue its own name. You call `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the code where you determine which screen is getting pushed.